# How to link to Symfony2's uploaded files?

Tags: symfony

I have my files uploaded in web/uploads/scripts.

How can I create a link in twig to make the file downloadable?

I checked path(), and asset() but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `asset('web/uploades/script/watheveryouwant.pdf')` to create a link to that resource. Learn more about the `asset()` function in [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#including-stylesheets-and-javascripts-in-twig).